# sum cellls based on 2 criteria and then remove rows that are not needed after summing

Tags: excel, vba

In the sample data below, I am trying to sum the rates if (1) the security in column A is duplicated and (2) if the description in column B says "Income" and "Special Cash." Then take the sum and replace the rate value in Row 1, Column C. Lastly, remove Row 3 as it is no longer needed.

```
         Column A        Column B         Column C
(Row 1) BIT US Equity    Income           .1167
(Row 2) BIT US Equity    ST Cap Gain      .1110
(Row 3) BIT US Equity    Special Cash     .13105
(Row 4) AOL US Equity    Regular Cash     .12345
(Row 5) RAC US Equity    LT Cap Gain      .10005
```

Any feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to S.O! Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code. Take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider.[Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/) or [Mid-Advanced Tutorials](http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/codes-examples-macros-how-tos-most-useful-basics-advanced/) and my [personal favorite](http://analystcave.com/excel-vba-tutorial/)

Comment: How do I mark Xabier's reply as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then the following should do what you expect:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A

For i = 1 To LastRow 'loop from row 1 to last
    CheckValue = ws.Cells(i, 1) 'get the value from Column A
    For x = 1 To LastRow 'do a second loop to check if we find any cell in Column B with "Special Cash"
        If ws.Cells(x, 2) = "Special Cash" And ws.Cells(x, 1) = CheckValue Then ' if Special Cash found and there is another cell with the same Column A value
            ws.Cells(x, 2) = "Income" 'replace Special Cash with Income
        End If
    Next x
Next i
    ws.Cells(1, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(C[-1],C[-3],RC[-3],C[-2],RC[-2])"
    'add sum formula to column D
    ws.Range("D1:D" & LastRow).FillDown
    'fill the formula to the lastrow
    ws.Range("D1:D" & LastRow).Copy
    'copy values returned by formula
    ws.Range("D1:D" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    'paste the values and get rid of formula
    ws.Columns("C:C").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    'delete column C and bring Column D into its place
    Range("$A$1:$C$" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlNo
    'remove duplicates
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response! Thanks a bunch this code worked beautifully!